# Flask - Attempted relative import in non-package

Tags: flask, importerror

Following this [tutorial](https://lepture.com/en/2018/structure-of-a-flask-project) on how to structure a `Flask` app, I have:

```
project/
       __init__.py
       app.py
       models/
             __init__.py
             base.py
```

**base.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**models/__init__.py**

```
from .base import db

def init_app(app):
    db.init_app(app)
```

**project/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app()
    from . import models, routes, services
    app = Flask(__name__)
    models.init_app(app)
    # routes.init_app(app)
    # services.init_app(app)
    return app
```

finally, in **app.py**, I try to run it:

```
from . import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=True, threaded=True, debug=True)
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
    from . import create_app
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Am I building it right, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are running your program by:

```
python project/app.py
```

In this case, you are not treat your "project" as a python package, which will raise the error you got. Instead, you can run your project with:

```
FLASK_APP=project.app flask run
```